# How to update Recycler view outside the activity which do not contain RecyclerViewAdapter object

Tags: java, android

Acually in my app  when the user get the notification of his task to be done and if he clicks the button done(notification customised with 2 buttons done and dismiss) then a tick mark will be there in his task list

I have maintained the task list using a recycler view..

For tick mark i have used a image view  which i have initially set invisibe but want to make it visible in selected tasks which have been done buy the user(He has clicked on the done button in notification)

Please help!!

Unable to do this

Comment: Post your adapter code

Comment: Thanks for your concern Mike...but now i am done with it i used shared prefernces as suggested by Dalwik

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't provide enough information so that we can try to help you, but hope this help.

first where do you store the status value of the tick Mark? if the user closed his app and opened it again would he be able to see the tick mark in his don tasks?

Personally i don't think you can make the same object visible and invisible in the same time depending on which item the image resides in the list, I tired it didn't work for me, you can only hide it in the entire list based on a criteria, but you can change the image icon based on a criteria on each item in recyclerview list.

in order to that you need to store the value of the tick mark in shared preferences (true or false), and also store something unique along with it like the task title, you will store it when the user clicks on "Done" and remove it from shared preferences when he the user clicks "dismiss" (in case he clicked on Done then Dismiss).

then in the recyclerview adapter in onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) you call the sharedpreferences something like this:

I am assuming you have custom ListItem called TaskList with the following fields at least (String title, boolean done = false)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {

    TaskList task = myTaskData.get(position);
    SharedPreferences TaskStatus = context.getSharedPreferences("IsDone",0);
    task.setDone(TaskStatus.getBoolean("userTask" + task.getTitle(), false));

    if (task.done) {
        holder.tickicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
    }else {
        holder.tickicon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_off);
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks Daiwik i got the trick..and i am now able to do it..thanku

Comment: hello, if my response helped you find the trick, please consider marking it as an answer. thanks